# Bash - File existence providing incorrect results

Tags: bash, file-exists

I have a file which contains a list of file, and I want to know if these files exist. I used this command:

```
while read line; do 
    filename="$(echo $line | cut -d';' -f4)"; 
    if [ ! -e "/some/path/$filename" ]; 
    then echo "/some/path/$filename"; 
    fi ; 
done < "../my_list_of_file"
```

This command returns to me every file listed as non existent, ex:

```
/some/path/my_listed_file.jpg
```

But when I do `ls /some/path/my_listed_file.jpg`, I can see that the file exists. What is wrong in my command?

Comment: Is this the last field on the line? I suspect your file has `CRLF` line endings, because it was created on Windows.

Comment: If `filename` is the last field in each line, this points to `my_list_of_file` having DOS line endings. The file name actually ends with a carriage return.

Comment: If this is the problem, use `dos2unix` to fix the file.

Comment: Also, let `read` split the line for your. `while IFS=$';\r' read -r _ _ _ filename _; do`. If the DOS line endings are the problem, you can switch to `IFS=";"` if you remove them from the file first.

Comment: Are the filenames in `my_list_of_file` without a path?

Comment: Yes ! Thank you it was indeed `CRLF` the problem, i thought about encoding problems but i havnt thought about `CRLF` ... Damn windows.

Comment: The Stack Overflow way to add the solution to your question is to write it as an Answer, rather than to edit it into your question (you are encouraged to provide answers to your own question if you can).  As a bonus, this means that you can accrue reputation points for both!  Please create an answer with the solution you inserted, then roll back the question to version 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to Barmar and chepner, the problem was the `CRLF` on the end of the file. 
Here is the working command :

```
while IFS=$';\r' read -r _ _ _ filename _; do 
    if [ ! -e "/some/path/$filename" ]; 
    then echo "/some/path/$filename"; 
    fi ; 
done < "../my_list_of_file"
```